# Gallery pulling pics from Hangouts even when Hangouts has been disabled

Tags: gallery, google-hangouts

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Victory running Android 4.1.2 that I want to let my son use for specific things only (camera, calculator, clock, etc.).  As such I have been disabling everything I can on it that will not be needed, and am using a lock program on everything else.

However, for some odd reason, the Gallery app is filled with pics that I sent via Hangouts a long time ago.  They were never on this phone to begin with, and the phone has been wiped.  I even made sure that I did not login with my Google acct before apps like Google+ and Hangouts were disabled.  Still, these pics appear and they do not have an option to disable.  They all appear in the gallery as Hangouts followed by the names of the people that were in the conversation.

**Is there anyway to remove these and keep them off?**  I hooked the phone up to my computer and located/deleted the cached pics (they were all sans extension).  Removing those kept you from browsing them in the albums (temporarily) but all the albums were still there, and eventually they came back.  I have also gone through all the apps I can think of in the Application Manager and cleared the data and cache, but the pics still remain (or immediately return).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the pics were coming in independently of any specific app.  Instead, they were coming from the Google Account Sync directly.  To disable this, I went into Settings -> Accounts -> Google Account and unchecked all the sync options.  Then I could clear the data from the Gallery app and all the pics and thumbnails went away.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Google Hangouts that is creating the problem, it is Google+ photos. When Google+ photos is enabled, it automatically stores all pictures posted on any and all Google services.Try accessing the settings of Google+ photos to attempt to disable whatever autosave setting may have been enabled. If the instructions above were no help, try disabling the Google+ photos app.

Comment: The pics were definitely coming from Hangouts, but the Hangouts and Google+ apps were obviously not what was pulling the pics in, since both were disabled in settings before I logged into my Google account.  No Google+ photos or Picasa apps on the phone, and no general settings in my Google+ account said anything about photo syncing.